# Memory usage and time for execution for another process using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, memory-management

I need the memory usage and processing time for an application loaded through another application. I am using C#. Currently I am using `Process.WorkingSet` to get memory usage
similarly `Process.TotalProcessTime` to get time for execution, but it doesn't give any value. So have you make any suggestions?

Comment: Working set does not indicated the amount of memory used. Also, it will makes no difference if launched as a sub process or on it's 'own'. On it's 'own' it is likely a sub process of explorer.exe or further up the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Use WMI to get this kind of info, well supported by the System.Management namespace.  Get started by downloading the [WMI Code Creator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), it lets you experiment with queries and can auto-generate the C# you'll need.

You want to query Win32_Process, it provides lots of info about a process.  PrivatePageCount would be a good measure for the amount of memory it uses that isn't shared by any other process.  KernelModeTime and UserModeTime gives you time spent executing code.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the link to download `WMI Code Creator`, I even didn't know about this before although I'd heard of using WMI.