# How do i get the used ram memory of a specific process?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a class i did:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);//System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);//Application.StartupPath; //Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);// +@"\workingDirectory";
            Logger.Write("workingDirectory: " + workingDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);//@"\ffmpeg.exe";
            Logger.Write("FfmpegFilename: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {
                string outPath = pathFileName;
                Logger.Write("Output Video File Directory: " + outPath);
                Logger.Write("Frame Rate: " + BitmapRate.ToString());
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
                b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                Logger.Write("psi.FileName: " + psi.FileName);
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                Logger.Write("psi.WorkingDirectory: " + psi.WorkingDirectory);
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                Logger.Write("ProcessStartInfo Arguments" + @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath);
                //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            try
            {
                int length;
                // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

                int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
                // Get the address of the first line.
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
                length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

                //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
                int j = bmp.Height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                    j--;
                }
                p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
```

When the process ffmpeg.exe is running i want to see/get the usage of memory of it .
Then i want to calculate that if the ffmpeg.exe usage of memory is over the ram i have on my pc then throw a message to the user.

This is the class im using to get the memory ram of my pc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class GetMemory
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo ci;

        public  ulong DisplayTotalRam()
        {
            ci = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();
            ulong ul = ci.TotalPhysicalMemory;//AvailablePhysicalMemory;
            return ul;
        }
    }
}
```

And using it in Form1 as :

```
gm = new GetMemory();
ulong ul = gm.DisplayTotalRam();
```

And it return:

```
6440865792
```

And my system is realy have installed now 6gb ram.

What i want is to warn or to throw a message when/if the ffmpeg.exe take too much ram .
So how can i get the process ram memory usage and how can i calculate it with the GetMemory class to see if its getting too much ram ?

Comment: Coding tip: don’t make a class for everything. `GetMemory` should not be a class.

Comment: minitech right it should be a function in Form1 i will change it later.

Comment: Please see this answer on StackOverflow: [Memory usage and time for execution of another process][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959045/memory-usage-and-time-for-execution-for-another-process-using-c

Comment: Once ffmpeg is using 6 GB it has been out of RAM for some time. your OS is always using ~2 GB at the least. You probably want to watch for when your process gets bumped into a page file.

Comment: Could you not just use `long memUsage = Process.GetProcessesByName("ffmpeg")[0].WorkingSet64;`

Comment: Typical XY problem. What are you going to do with the answer to this question? Pop up a message saying the user should buy more RAM? You have no control over ffmpeg's memory usage. You probably are sending it more data than it can process. Your real question is: how do I efficiently record video. Perhaps you should not try to encode it in realtime.